# Turn section plane hatches off

Tags: autodesk-forge

In viewer 7.35 a new setting was added:

> Setting to turn section plane hatches on and off. This setting does not apply to the section box.

I am however not able to find this setting anywhere. Could anyone share some information and/or documentation on the use of this?

Does anyone know if we able to remove only hatches, but keep and outline and therefore be able to snap to the edges in the sectioned geometry?

Thank you all in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to our engineering team, only Section planes support section hatches. Section box won't have that.

Although the viewer of BIM360 Docs built on top of Forge Viewer, it doesn't get updates as the new version of Forge Viewer released. It will take some time to merge the changes from the new Forge Viewer.

Comment: I have seen before that the section Box does not support hatches, but in the changeling for 7.35 (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/#id6) it says that a setting is added to turn the hatches on and off, therefore I assume this setting is also added to the viewer code? Can this be used in our own implementation of the Forge Viewer, meaning not through BIM360.

Comment: If your Forge Viewer version used in your own app equals 7.35 and newer, you should see this option in the setting panel. Please type `LMV_VIEWER_VERSION` in your dev console to check the version.

Comment: And if I do not want to go through the settings panel? Is it possible to toggle, like ghosting can be toggled with 'NOP_VIEWER.setGhosting(true)'?

Comment: Try `NOP_VIEWER.prefs.set(Autodesk.Viewing.Private.Prefs3D.DISPLAY_SECTION_HATCHES, true)` or `NOP_VIEWER.getExtension("Autodesk.Section").displaySectionHatches( true )`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Is this not what you are looking for ?

Under settings -> Configuration -> Display section -> Display Section Hatches

Comment: I do not have that option in my BIM360 account... Strange! 
But I was also looking for a way to toggle that in the viewer code, not in settings panel.